# I like to put three dots, "..." at the end of my image files' IPTC Core Title metadata

Tags: image, jpeg, exiftool, iptc

I like to put three dots, "..." at the end of my image files' IPTC Core Title metadata

Help is much appreciated!

Edit: In bulk for 1000s of files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [exiftool](https://exiftool.org), you could use this command

For Windows CMD
`exiftool "-Title<${Title}..." /path/to/files/`

For other shells
`exiftool '-Title<${Title}...' /path/to/files/`

This command creates backup files.  Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add [`-r`](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: Thank you again! Can you tell me what this means, "recurse into subdirectories"?

Comment: It means to process all the files that are in any directories below the main one listed.  Given the above example of `/path/to/files/`, it would process any files in that directory, as well as files in `/path/to/files/Sublevel1/` and the files in `/path/to/files/Sublevel1/Sublevel2/`  and so on.

Comment: It got a bit more complicated. I only need to put the dots after files which titles have been cut (not all my files needs cut). You answered my previous question, how to cut titles to given character number and even  to cut it at whole words. Now I think what I need is a solution to put ... Ok. I don't even know how to achieve this. ..... This is the task: 1. Cut every title to e.g. 160 characters considering whole words to stay. 2. Which files' titles been cut, put three dots at the end. Maybe Adobe Bridge or Windows Explorer can sort the files by "(Modified) Date"?

Comment: Had to dig that one up.  Use the same command, just put the three dots between the brace and the quote, e.g. `"-Title<${Title;s/^(.{1,195}(?!\w)).*/$1/s}..."`

Comment: Thanks again. I guess "195" is the number of characters to cut at? Am I right?

Comment: Ok I got the command "exiftool -if "length($Title)>195" "-Title<${Title;s/^(.{1,195}(?!\w)).*/$1/s}..." "H:\111 PIXX Jpg\New folder" -overwrite_original" ... Both the numbers, currently "195" needs to be adjusted to cut at a specific length?

Comment: Probably yes, I don't recall.

Comment: It was a stupid question. I asked before I thought about it. It works well. Thank you